# Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable function satisfying $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R} $ Show that $f(x) = ce^x.$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives

Hi guys I have been stuck on this question for while now, its a practice problem for my first year real analysis class and I have an exam coming up soon, so I really need your help! Something is telling me that considering the function $g(x) = (f(x))/e^x$ might be useful, but I'm not really sure! Thanks for your help! Here's the question:

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} $ be a differentiable function satisfying $f'(x) = f(x)$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. Show
that $f(x) = ce^x$ for some constant $c \in \mathbb{R}.$

Comment: @http://math.stackexchange.com/users/222805/%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%b5%e0%a5%87%e0%a4%a8%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%a6%e0%a5%8d%e0%a4%b0-prasad  Please refrain from editing old questions with trivial edits

Answer (score 2):

Solve the basic differential equation $\;y'=y\;$ :

$$\frac{dy}{dx}=y\iff\int\frac{dy}y=\int dx\implies\log y=x+C\implies y=ke^x \;\;(K=e^C)$$

Comment: same time Don ...

Comment: Ah, so I see, @Don

Comment: I mean, we answer this question at the same time. We are connected somehow.

Comment: "somehow"? Via internet! :)

Comment: tienes razon. El frio me tiene desquiciado.

Comment: A mí no: estamos pasando un invierno calentito.

Comment: En que estado estas? Aqui en NY estamos a -1C ahorita.

Comment: En ningún estado gringo: en Israel.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably what you had in mind: If $f : \mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is differentiable with $f'=f$, then $g(x)=e^{-x}f(x)$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and $g'=-e^{-x}f+e^{-x}f'=0$. So, by the mean value theorem, $f(x)-f(0)=f'(c)x = 0$ for some $c \in (0,x)$. It follows that $f(x)=f(0)$ for all $x$. So $f(x)=f(0)e^{x}$.

Answer (score 1):

$$ f' = f \implies \int \frac{df}{f} = \int  dx \implies\ln f = x + K$$

$$ \therefore f = e^{x + K} = (e^K)e^x \implies f(x) = Ce^x$$

$ c = e^K \in \mathbb{R} $

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be such that $f(x)=f'(x)$, and derive $\frac{e^x}{f(x)}$:
$$\left[\frac{e^x}{f(x)}\right]'=\frac{e^xf(x)-e^xf'(x)}{f(x)^2}=0$$
So the ratio $\frac{e^x}{f(x)}$ is constant, and $f(x)=Ce^x$.

Comment: Why would $f$ never be zero? It's easier to just derive $\frac{f(x)}{e^x}$ (this way, no problem).